# Mandatory field in generated workbook

Tags: excel, vba

How can I add code in a generated new workbook?

I have a project generating a new workbook based on the information input by the user.
After generating a new workbook, some fields are required. The user cannot save the file, if these mandatory fields are not filled.

Is it possible to code a new generated workbook?

The generating a new workbook is working but the fields that are mandatory is not working in a new generated workbook.

Comment: How do you generate the Workbook? Is it an XLSM or XLSX file?

Comment: Use a template workbook that already contains the code.

Comment: _some fields are required. The user cannot save the file, if these mandatory fields are not filled_ This seems like an xy problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem It seems you want to do some validation and ensure people don't save incomplete data. If you did work out a way to stop them saving, there's nothing stopping them copy/pasting into a different workbook (without macros) and saving that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to add code to a new xlsm workbook  programmatically.

Use this to add a workbook and place a worksheet change event into the Sheet1 module.

```
'Add refrence to "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 library"

Sub AddSht_AddCode()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim xPro As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim xCom As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim xMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim xLine As Long

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    With wb
        Set xPro = .VBProject
        Set xCom = xPro.VBComponents("Sheet1")
        Set xMod = xCom.CodeModule

        With xMod
            xLine = .CreateEventProc("Change", "Worksheet")
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, " if Range("a1")=vbnullstring then msgbox ("WTF dude?")"
            xLine = xLine + 1
             ....
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```